# xparse losing default values of optional parameters after environment

Tags: environments, xparse, optional-arguments

Some code that used to work has stopped working on a newly updated system (revision 61040 of l3packages, from what I can tell; I don't have a version number for which it did work), and I'm trying to understand if this is a new bug or if I am/was doing something wrong.

In short:  for an environment defined using `NewDocumentEnvironment` with an optional parameter with a specified default (a `O` type parameter), the value of the parameter is correctly set to the specified value or to the default in the pre-environment-body code -- but if the default value was used then the parameter value reverts to `-NoValue-` in the post-environment-body code.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{env}{ O{a default value} }{%
  Before time began, we had 1=[#1]%
}{%
  but now 1=[#1].
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{env}[A specified argument] foo \end{env}
\begin{env} bar \end{env}
\end{document}

% Expected output:
%   Before time began, we had 1=[A specified argument] foo but now 1=[A specified argument].
%   Before time began, we had 1=[a default value] bar but now 1=[a default value].
% Observed output:
%   Before time began, we had 1=[A specified argument] foo but now 1=[A specified argument].
%   Before time began, we had 1=[a default value] bar but now 1=[-NoValue-].
```

Anything that I'm doing wrong, or any tips?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/712. There is already a pull request with a correction, it will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ulrike Fischer in the comments, this was fixed with LaTeX release [2021-11-15-PL1](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/releases/tag/release-2021-11-15-PL1).